# How to expose multiple cxf:jaxws-service via a single http:inbound-endpoint in Mule ESB

Tags: cxf, esb, mule, endpoint

I am trying to expose multiple service interfaces via a single endpoint in mule as per this configuration:
Each service interface has a slightly different url 
(1)  http://localhost/services/Login
(2)  http://localhost/services/Admin

However I get the error
"Soap 1.1 endpoint already registered on address"

Any tips on how to do this?  I merely want to use the cxf service to marshall/unmarshall between SOAP and Java and at a later date to provide ws-security.

```
<flow name="flow_Services">
    <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost/services" exchange-pattern="request-response">

    <choice>
        <when expression="inbound:http.request=/services/Login" evaluator="header">
            <cxf:jaxws-service serviceClass="com.ws.client.generated.Login" />
            <component><spring-object bean="Login"/></component>
        </when>

        <when expression="inbound:http.request=/services/Admin" evaluator="header">
            <cxf:jaxws-service serviceClass="com.ws.client.generated.Admin" />
            <component><spring-object bean="Admin"/></component>
        </when>
    </choice>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple http inbound-endpoints with the same hostname and port, but different paths. Here's a simple example I tested:

```
<flow name="Flow" doc:name="EchoFlow">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" 
         host="localhost" port="8084" path="services/hello" />
    <cxf:jaxws-service port="80" serviceClass="mypackage.ServiceInterface" />
    <component class="mypackage.ServiceClass" />
</flow>
<flow name="Flow2" doc:name="EchoFlow2">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" 
         host="localhost" port="8084" path="services/goodbye" />
    <cxf:jaxws-service port="80" serviceClass="mypackage.ServiceInterfaceTwo" />
    <component class="mypackage.ServiceClassTwo" />
</flow>
```

Here we're hosting two web services; both endpoint URLs start

```
http://localhost:8084/services/
```

but have different endings (hello and goodbye). The ServiceInterface class looks like this:

```
package mypackage;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public interface ServiceInterface {
    @WebMethod
    String sayHello(String name);
}
```

And the ServiceClass looks like this:

```
package mypackage;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService(endpointInterface = "mypackage.ServiceInterface")
public class ServiceClass implements ServiceInterface {
    public String sayHello(String name) {
        return "Hello "+name;
    } 
}
```

ServiceInterfaceTwo and ServiceClassTwo are the same, but instead of sayHello() it has sayGoodbye().